Options in \psaxes
I'm using \psaxes and I wonder if there is a way of removing some of the last numbers of both axes (maintaining the remaining ones)? For instance, in
 \psaxes[linewidth=1pt]{->}%. (0,0)(20,24)[$x$,-90][$y$,180]

remove the numbers 16, 17, 18, 19 in x-axis, and the numbers 21, 22, 23 in y-axis. Further, there is a way of control the length of the ticks in each axis?

See documentation for tick length!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=0.5cm,yunit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(21,25)
\psaxes[linewidth=1pt,labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(20,24)[$x$,-90][$y$,180]
\psaxes[linewidth=1pt](0,0)(15,20)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}



That's it! With thanks.

One more question: there is a way of control the length of the ticks in each axis?

See documentation (texdoc pst-plot), page 49f: 9.17. Option tickstyle. and 9.18. Options ticksize, xticksize, yticksize
